# Meanshift for feature vectors (e.g. SIFT)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, sift, pattern-recognition, feature-extraction

I am searching for a way to calculate a reasonable average feature vector for robust tracking. Currently I am recording an object from all sides. Then I extract SIFT features in each frame and match them frame by frame. So as a result I obtain multiple chains of features which describe the same keypoint.
Since these feature vectors all have slightly different values, I am trying to find an average SIFT feature for each of these chains. According to the following paper one can generate such a feature by applying meanshift clustering (which sound reasonable to me) 
http://www.tnt.uni-hannover.de/papers/data/940/main.pdf

Since openCV seems to only support meanShift for images (2-Dimensional), I am wondering if there is another lib I can use to calculate such a mean vector. If not, any hints on how to implemnt this function is appreciated.

Does such a mean-shift generally makes sense for my problem? Since I am recording the object free-hand I might have many frames from one perspective and less from another. This would result in a biased shift into the feature vector direction which was recoreded for a longer time, right?

Thanks!

Comment: Your matching the next frame features with the last frame feature's and than there are some features which are approximately same ?

Comment: Yes. During feature matching you most probably will not match two identical feature vectors. I match them by using simple distance threshold between the matches and an additional ratio test for the second best match.

Comment: What do you actually need the "averaged" feature for? I implemented something similar a while back, and simple distance-based matching (like you describe in your comment) was sufficient.